What does Gain mean when LTSpice plots Gain vs Frequency in AC analysis?
I am trying to simulate the frequency response of a trans-impedance amplifier in LTspice, with a current source input, as shown below:

My question is when doing ac analysis, the gain that LTspice plots, is it voltage gain (as in output voltage by the voltage at input node)? Or does it plot trans-impedance gain? (output voltage by input current) since my input is a current source. If it is the former, is there any way I can plot trans-impedance gain vs frequency in LTspice?


Depends on how you have it set up and how you probed your nodes. Based on your dimensions, it seems you have an attenuator.

Change the vertical axis to linear and see what the units are.

I suspect that nobody but you knows where V(n005) is. If you are going to properly name nodes I also strongly suggest that you use a white background on your AC plot.

Are the "center" points of M1 and M wired to "anything"?

@Andyaka I have updated the schematic, my apologies I had had a long day when I had asked this question.

When you do an AC analysis and then measure the voltage at a point the result will be a plot of the voltage at that point vs. frequency. The default plot is in decibels referenced to 1 V, so if there is 1 V at the point you measure it will show 0 dB. If there is 2 V at the point you measure it will show
$$
20\cdot log(2~V) = 6.02~dBV
$$
If you plot a current it will do the same, except the decibel results will be referenced to 1 A.
Changing the vertical axis (right click the left scale of the plot) setting from decibel to linear or logarithmic will plot the voltage directly, so 1 V plots as 1 V.
The voltage at a point will depend on the voltage or current source's small signal AC analysis AC amplitude setting. Typically you set it to 1 so that the results are referenced to the input signal and you can read gain directly in dB or as a multiplier. For example set the AC amplitude to 1 at the input of an amplifier with a gain of 20 and the plot will show
$$
20\cdot log(1~V\cdot 20) = 26.02~dBV
$$
or 20 if the vertical scale is set to logarithmic or linear.
If you set the amplitude to something other than 1 you will need to take that into account in your results, for example setting it to 2 will multiply the result by 2, so an amp with a gain of 20 would now show
$$
20\cdot log(2~V\cdot 20) = 32.04~dBV
$$
or 40 if the vertical scale is set to logarithmic or linear.

Also note that if you use a current source with amplitude set to 1, measure the voltage across that source and use logarithmic or linear scale it will plot the impedance vs. frequency, which is rather handy.

That's an underrated comment - focusing on making the AC currents and voltages "real values" instead of 1 is just making life harder for you - the simulator has already turned the circuit into a linear model and will happily tell you that your amplifier outputs 1 kV (which is fine).

Assuming that node V(n005) is the output i.e. the node on the right-side terminal of the 10 kΩ resistor (R2), a little progress can be made: -

Your AC signal current level is defined as 10 μA (AC 10u)
The low frequency gain of a TIA is the feedback resistor R2
The gain is volts per amp for a TIA
10 μA × 10 kΩ = 0.1 volts
In dB terms (dB volts to be precise) that is -20 dB

At higher frequencies gain will deteriorate but, it does look as if your plot would satisfy my musings above.

My question is when doing ac analysis, the gain that LTspice plots, is
it voltage gain?

It plots the output voltage for the given AC input sources. Your only defined AC source is 10 μA (Iin1).

or does it plot trans-impedance gain?

It is (on this occasion) plotting transimpedance gain (because your only AC source is current) but, be aware that the true plot is output voltage and it will plot that voltage in the presence of several AC sources (leading to confusion if you are not on the ball). You only have 1 AC source so, on this occasion it's clear-cut.


the gain that LTspice plots, is it voltage gain?

You plotted the voltage of the net N005. Look at the plot's expression: It's V(n005). So the LTspice plots the measurement in dBs:
$$
\mathrm{V_{dB}=20 \log (V(N005))}
$$
For example, if the amplitude of the voltage measured at that node is about 700μV you'll see about -62 dB.
The phase plot is the phase difference between the voltage at N005 and the reference signal which is the current source (it has the AC command in definition, so it's the reference).

is there anyway I can plot trans-impedance gain vs frequency in LTSpice ?

Change the expression of the plot to whatever you want e.g. V(N005)/I(Iin1) by right-clicking on the plot's name in the plot window and entering the expression manually.

NOTE: You are using the 4-pin NMOS model (nmos4) and you left the substrate pin unconnected. The 4-pin model is not supposed to be used like that. Either use nmos model or if you insist on the nmos4 model connect the substrate to somewhere suitable.

I have connected the body pin of the nmoses to the source, but its not rendering for some reason.
